# How to pass a parameter to stored procedure in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, m

I'm trying to execute a stored procedure in Power BI, where a user can input a data value in the parameter.

```
let
Source = Sql.Database("nj1tstsql12", "GI_MASTER", [Query="exec 
dal_ANALYTICS_TIME_SERIES_SUMMARY_BY_SECTOR " &AsOfDate])
in
Source
```

I keep on receiving this error:

```
Expression.Error: We cannot apply operator & to types Text and DateTime.
Details:
Operator=&
Left=exec dal_ANALYTICS_TIME_SERIES_SUMMARY_BY_SECTOR 
Right=12/10/2018 12:00:00 AM
```

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried converting AsOfDate to text?

Comment: Yeah, you need your date formatted as a string if you're going to include it in your query string.

Comment: Yeah, tried converting the parameter value to text, but end up getting a different value when trying to execute the sp.

DataSource.Error: Microsoft SQL: Incorrect syntax near '/'.
Details:
    DataSourceKind=SQL
    DataSourcePath=nj1tstsql12;GI_MASTER
    Message=Incorrect syntax near '/'.
    Number=102
    Class=15

Comment: You need to convert date to text formatted the way SQL server understands (i.e, "2018-12-25")

Answer (score 0):

As the others said on comments, you need to change the data into Text format. You made a syntax error when you did, that's why you got another error. Please try below:

```
let
Source = Sql.Database("nj1tstsql12", 
                      "GI_MASTER", 
                      [Query="exec dal_ANALYTICS_TIME_SERIES_SUMMARY_BY_SECTOR '" & Date.ToText(AsOfDate) & "'"])
in
Source
```

Comment: Glad to help :)